# Como gerar um token de vida longa para postagem de informações no facebook

Tags: php, facebook

Estou tentando gerar um token para postagem de informações no facebook na minha página com php o script ate faz a postagem mas o token que consigo pegar so tem uma hora de vida.

como faço para criar um token que tenha tempo indefinido ou reatualizar o token automaticamente?
estou usando o https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/ do facebook

mas não consigo gerar nenhum token com mais de 1 hora.

Comment: Você pode renovar o token quando o token expirar. Muito antigamente existia o `offline_access`, mas isso foi removido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - Você pode renovar o seu "short-lived-token";

2 - A partir do seu "short-lived-token" você pode obter um "long-lived-token" com o endpoint:

```
GET /oauth/access_token?  
grant_type=fb_exchange_token&           
client_id={app-id}&
client_secret={app-secret}&
fb_exchange_token={short-lived-token}
```

Documentação: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension/?locale=pt_BR

Comment: tem algum jeito d eu gerar o short tbm pelo php ? assim meu script seria auto suficiente eu nao precisaria entrar no fb toda hora pra faze isso

Comment: Os endpoints de autenticação do Facebook são independetes de linguaguem, você pode implementar em PHP ou qualquer outra linguagem. Você pode trabalhar no PHP usando um short lived token e sempre renovando ele quando expirar, ou então obter um long lived, tudo isso pelo seu código PHP.

Comment: legal muito obrigado. vou pesquisar mais sobre.